# Why OrderBy filter for descending is not working?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects with a property containing notificationemailid.when iam sorting the data in descending order it isnot working

```
0: {EmailNotificationID: 50, Client: "Hanson", Ranch: "Bricoleur Vineyards", Block: "Block 4",…}
1: {EmailNotificationID: 53, Client: "Esther Suen", Ranch: "Lucunda Vineyard", Block: "Block 1",…}
2: {EmailNotificationID: 58, Client: "Benziger Family Winery", Ranch: "Sunny Slope", Block: "Block A1",…}
3: {EmailNotificationID: 66, Client: "Arista Winery", Ranch: "Estate", Block: "Block Bee Tree",…}
4: {EmailNotificationID: 63, Client: "Edgar Lantz", Ranch: "Sam Brannon", Block: "Block 2E_3",…}
5: {EmailNotificationID: 67, Client: "Benziger Family Winery", Ranch: "Sunny Slope", Block: "Block A2",…}
6: {EmailNotificationID: 68, Client: "Benziger Family Winery", Ranch: "Sunny Slope", Block: "Block A2",…}
7: {EmailNotificationID: 70, Client: "Edgar Lantz", Ranch: "Sam Brannon", Block: "Block 1E_2 South",…}
8: {EmailNotificationID: 71, Client: "Stein", Ranch: "Windsor Oaks Vineyards", Block: "Block 10D1",…}
9: {EmailNotificationID: 73, Client: "Williams Selyem Winery", Ranch: "Saitone Vineyard",…}
10: {EmailNotificationID: 74, Client: "Pier Oddone", Ranch: "Home", Block: "Block C.S",…}
11: {EmailNotificationID: 76, Client: "Trentadue Winery", Ranch: "Estate", Block: "Block 405 PS",…}
12: {EmailNotificationID: 75, Client: "Landmark", Ranch: "Hop Kiln Vineyard", Block: "Block 25",…}
```

```html
  <tr ng-repeat="Notification in Notificationlist | limitTo:5:5*(page-1) | orderBy : '-EmailNotificationID':false ">
    <td><span class="val1">{{Notification.Client}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="val1">{{Notification.Ranch}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="val1">{{Notification.Block}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="val1">{{Notification.SensorType}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="val1">{{Notification.Depth}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="val1">{{Notification.Criteria}}</span></td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
       <span class="val1">{{Notification.Value1}}{{Notification.Symbol}}
       </span>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right">
       <span class="val1">{{Notification.Value2}}{{Notification.Value2==NULL?'':Notification.Symbol}}
       </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <!--<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="DeleteButton" 
                    text="Submit" name="Submit"
                    ng-click="DeleteAlertNotification()">
          Delete
        </button>-->
        <i style="color:#ff7675;font-size:25px;padding-left:25%;cursor:pointer"
           ng-click="confirmDeletion(Notification.EmailNotificationID)"
           class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </td>
```

Actual data should be in decending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `orderBy : '-EmailNotificationID':false` to `orderBy: 'EmailNotificationID':true`.

The prefix `-` before the name of the property is used to indicate descending ordering. So `orderBy: 'EmailNotificationId':true` is equal to `orderBy: '-EmailNotificationId'`.

`orderBy` filter should be placed before `limitTo` filter.
So, `<tr ng-repeat="Notification in Notificationlist | orderBy:'-EmailNotificationID' | limitTo:5:5*(page-1)>`

Comment: I added like what you said ,it is showing EmailNotificationID  66 as first record but expected is  EmailNotificationID 75 as first record.And if  i do ascending order by it is working properly.I need descending order by.Thanks

Comment: There may be an issue caused by the use of `limitTo`. Remove it and give it a try to see if expected behavior is met.

Comment: Thanks if i place first orderby filter and next limit to filter , it is working as expected

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="Notification in Notificationlist |  orderBy : '-EmailNotificationID' |limitTo:5:5*(page-1)" > is the correct syntax.Thanks Fotis papadamis for your suggestion

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it easier for future searchers.